# How to run audio settings program without Unity?

Tags: 12.04, unity, sound

In Unity desktop, there is a sound menu at the top of the screen where I can change volume and input/output devices (screenshot).

[image]

I'm wondering how can I run this program without Unity?

(Just in case, I know about `alsamixer`, but it's not what I'm looking for.)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by avoiding Unity here? Are you using a different desktop environment (ie - Gnome, KDE, etc)? Do you want to adjust it via terminal, keyboard commands, something else?

Comment: @Shauna, I use i3 windows manager without desktop environment but I need this program to adjust my audio settings sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

1. In a terminal or by hitting Alt-F2 write:
2. `gnome-control-center sound`
3. Hit Enter and you'll see the desired window.

Good luck!

P.S. If you are using a different launcher, such as Synapse, you can invoke it the same way.